# Change URI Pattern in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in the routes.rb

```
get 'search#search', to: 'search#search', as: 'search'
```

and if I `rails routes` it returns the following:

```
search GET    /search%23search(.:format)        search#search
```

I would like to change the `/search%23search` to `search/search`

How can I do this?

Comment: I just created a `search_controller.rb` along with the view, in order to search for products from there. And this is the route `get 'search', to: 'search#search' as: 'search'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails you write as:

```
get 'search/search', to: 'search#search', as: 'search'
```

This will result to:

```
search GET    /search/search(:format)        search#search
```

Comment: And if I want to make that page the root page `root 'search/search', to: 'search#search', as: 'search'` is this correct?

Comment: just write `root  'search#search'`